# 82 Corolla manual. Have a slow leak in the transmission propeller shaft. Now car won't shift into any gear when running

Tags: transmission

I have a Corolla Ke70 with the manual 4 speed transmission. There was a slow leak between in the oil seal and propeller shaft. The leak isn't very big. However, I have left this leak for almost a year now.

My car sat undriven for maybe 2 weeks now, and when I tried to use it, I can't shift the shifter into any gear. For gears 1,2,3,4, I can't physically move the shifter into gear. For reverse, it grinds when I force to shift to reverse.

I tried shifting with the engine turned off, and I noticed that it is a little difficult to put into gear, almost as if there is some sort of resistance.

I checked the clutch master cylinder and fluid level seems to be okay, although dirty brown in color.

Did the car possibly run out of transmission fluid?

The last time I drove the car, I didn't see any problems with it. Although I have noticed that it is sometimes crunching gears when going into reverse.

Answer (score 1):

The transmission box will happily engage even if left with absolutely no lubrication. Well, it will probably quickly overheat.

From what you tell, it is not the gearbox at fault, it is your clutch that refuses to disengage. It happens when left unused for long - the clutch disk sticks to the flywheel.

What you can do depends on how good driver you are and if there is enough clearance to another cars or other obstacles.

Try this:

1. Run the engine at idle for few minutes, then cut it off.
2. Engage 3rd or 4th. If you fail both, start and cut off the engine and try again.
3. Press the clutch pedal all the way to the floor and press the brake pedal as much as you can and try (maybe few times) to start the engine.

90% this will unstick your clutch and will allow the car to run normally (provided no other problems developed in the meantime).